# Deviance residuals in Cox Model

Tags: survival, residuals, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

Based on this article: Click [here](http://www.mayo.edu/research/documents/biostat-58pdf/doc-10027288), the martingale residuals is a sum of each martingale residual per subject from counting process data.
So, if deviance residuals in Cox regression are defined by:
$$r_i = sign(M_i)\sqrt{-M_i - \delta_i log(\delta_i - M_i)}$$
where:
$M_i$ - martingale residuals and $\delta_i$ - event indicator,

can I use this formula to compute deviance residuals in counting process data (putting for $M_i$ sum of my martingale residuals)?